# How do I prove that the triangle must be obtuse?

Tags: geometry

Suppose you are given a triangle where the center of the nine-point circle lies on the circumcircle of the triangle. It is obvious that the triangle is obtuse, but how can you formally prove that the triangle must be obtuse?

Comment: Does such a triangle exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that your triangle is acute.  Then the orthocenter and circumcenter lie in the interior of the triangle.  The nine-point center is the midpoint of these two points, hence lies in the interior of your triangle, by convexity.

Because the circumcircle intersects the triangle only at the three vertices, it is therefore impossible for the nine-point center to lie on the circumcircle.

This shows that such triangles may not be acute.  In addition, they may not be right.  To see why, recall that the nine-point center of a right triangle is given by the midpoint of the hypotenuse (which does not lie on the circumcircle).

Comment: @A Walker Thank You!! So I should prove it by cases that bring me to contradictions right? Could you explain to me or be more specific about convexity please.

Comment: When I say convexity, I just mean to say that the triangle is a convex shape: if two points lie in the interior of a triangle, the line segment connecting them lies inside the triangle as well.  (In particular, the nine-point center lies inside the triangle.)